# Цепочка запросов к серверу Angular 2+

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular, angular5

Есть массив с номерами заказов.

```
let arr = [123, 456, 789]
```

Нужно с помощью pipable операторов сделать последовательные запросы к серверу, передав в каждом запросе номер заказа. 
Могу это сделать в цикле, но нужно именно с помощью Observables.

Comment: я же по-моему показывал вам как это сделать)

Comment: задавайте вопрос немного обширнее пожалуйста, есть массив с номерами заказов, допустим этот в примере, нужно куда-то сделать 3 запроса, а потом что?

Comment: Я что-то запутался совсем (

Comment: давайте по порядку, просто опишите алгоритм что нужно сделать

Comment: я просто опускаю все моменты последующей обработки для простоты

Comment: Потом из каждого отдельного ответа я достаю обьекты и строю таблицу. Но дальше я знаю, что делать. Мне непонятно, как у Observables дождаться всех ответов с сервера, чтобы собрать их все вместе.

Comment: Я делаю первый запрос к серверу, потом в map собираю массив и по этому массиву нужно сделать новые запросы, дождаться ответа собрать из запросов массив обьектов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть массив с номерами заказов:

```
const orders = [123, 456, 789];
```

Нужно сделать `GET` запросы на API и получить информацию о заказе по его номеру:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

forkJoin(
    // вымышленный сервис с методом
    service.getOrderById(123),
    service.getOrderById(456)
).subscribe((orders) => {
    // `orders` - это массив с инфо
    console.log(orders);
});
```

`forkJoin` - это аналог `Promise.all`, только `Promise.all` не умеет работать с потоками, массив с номерами заказов может быть любой длины:

```
const orders = [.....]; // массив длиной 10

forkJoin(
    orders.map((order) => service.getOrderById(order))
).subscribe((orders) => {
    console.log(orders);
});
```

Comment: А где мне обработать ответ сервера после каждого запроса? Мне нужно собрать массив из обьектов

Comment: у вас будет массив из объектов внутри `subscribe`, вы попробуйте хотя бы для начала на банальном примере :)

Comment: Я пытаюсь сразу на проекте делать)

Comment: так каши не сваришь + ничего не поймете, проделайте все пошагово как в моем ответе и тогда поймете как это работает

Comment: Да, спасибо большое за помощь!)